# Mulesoft Dataweave timestamp conversion issues

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave

I am trying to convert a string from payload to format dd/mm/yyyy

Here is the string from payload:

> Mar 9, 2016 04:19:33 PM

My Dataweave conversion:

`timestamp: payload.metas.datas[0].timestamp as :datetime {format: "MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"}`

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot coerce a :string to a :datetime, caused by :Text 'Mar 9, 2016 04:19:33 PM' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: DateTimeBuilder[, ISO, null, 2016-03-09, 16:19:33], type org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeBuilder.

Can anyone advise how this should be done ?

Thanks a lot. 
Mike

Answer (score 2):

Date could not be parsed as it cant decide for timezone. You can try following code

```
timestamp: payload.metas.datas[0].timestamp as :localdatetime {format: "MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"} as :string {format: "dd/mm/yyyy"}
```

HTH

Comment: Although it's inferred, I think it would be helpful to explicitly state why this is the case: `:datetime` expects a timezone, while `:localdatetime` does not.

Comment: As per [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-reference-documentation#datetime) `:datetime` is the conjunction of 'Date' + 'Time' + 'TimeZone'. While `:localdatetime` is the conjunction of 'Date' + 'Time'. Where Local timezone is used.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
timestamp: payload.metas.datas[0].timestamp as LocalDateTime {format: "MMM d, yyyy H:mm:ss a"} as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}
```